# How to get all decimal points in in ruby? ( HOLD)

Tags: ruby, floating-point

The following shows that when I use the `to_f` method to covert a string to a floating point number and the last decimal point is dropped. How can preserve all decimal points in a given number?

```
irb(main):002:0> value='1.7.8'
=> "1.7.8"
irb(main):003:0> value.to_f
=> 1.7
```

Some context:
I am writing the the value to a file and If I write it as a string I get the quotes `'1.7.8'`. What I am looking for infact is `1.7.8`. Hope that makes sense.

**EDIT:**

I see the error in my question so I'm trying to close it however I can only vote to close it.

just to clarify what I've found is actually contrary to what I said above.

turns out if I write the string '1.7' to a file it is written as `'1.7'` but with the string `'1.7.8'` it is written as `1.7.8`. I'm just trying to understand why this is occurring.

Comment: What are you expecting? `1.7.8` makes no sense mathematically.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking. If there is more than one decimal point, it is not a number.

Comment: @August: Ok so let me rephrase the question. Currently the result I am looking for is `1.7.8` Can this be achieved?

Comment: What class is `1.7.8` if it is not a string?

Comment: @greenpool Not as a floating point number. It is fine as a string.

Comment: What is the reason for the attempted conversion to float?

Comment: This seems to be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I see, you want to write a string to a file, but don't want quotes written.  Are you sure the quotes are being written? I suggest you delete the question and rethink it.  As it stands, it will keep attracting downvotes and votes to close.

Answer (score 1):

To write it to a file simply write it like so:

```
value = "1.7.8"
File.open("file") { |f| f.puts("#{value}") }
```

The string in the file will not have quotes around it.

Comment: `f.puts value` is enough, or just `IO.write("file", value)` or `File.write("file", value)`